# Facebook auth token stops working after logging out

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the following URL to get a Facebook Auth Token for managing Pages and Page Events...

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECTURL&scope=manage_pages,create_event&response_type=token`

This goes through the authorization process and returns the token, which gets saved in my database. I then try to do the following to retrieve the thumbnail images of people attending one of the Page's Events...

```
function fbEventRSVPPhotos($eventID){
    $authToken = eto_get_option('eto_auth_fbauthtoken') //pulled from database;
    $json = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $eventID ."/attending?access_token=" . $authToken);
    $attendees = json_decode($json, true);
    echo '<div class=attendee-photos>';
    foreach($attendees['data'] as $attendee) {
        echo '<img class="facebook-thumb toggleTooltip" title="' . $attendee['name'] . ' is attending" src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $attendee['id'] . '/picture?type=square">';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This function works great for when I am logged in to Facebook, however once I log out I get the following...

`Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/MYEVENTID/attending?access_token=MYTOKEN) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in PATHTOSCRIPT on line 94
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PATHTOSCRIPT on line 97`

And then it continues to show this PHP error even after logging back in. I essentially have to regenerate the auth token every time I log back in.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: I think this is expected behavior. Check [this Article](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) for more information.

Comment: *Scenario 4: User logs out of Facebook* sounds like my problem, however they're reasoning for it happening is because I didn't ask for `offline_access` when authenticating, but `offline_acces`s is deprecated and I can't request it any more. How do I get around this or solve it without offline access?

Comment: I haven't worked much with the Facebook API for a while (it changes every month or so), but as far as I know, the maximum you can get is a token that lasts 60 days (as long as the user doesn't log out, etc). Facebook posted some information about migration [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

Comment: Here is a link for the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: So, if I'm correctly understanding this, unless I'm logged in to the Facebook account that manages the Page's Event, I won't be able to pull RSVP info from the Event with any access token, as `offline_access` is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to destroy the session `$facebook->destroySession()`, not invalidate the token. Logging out is one of the ways to invalidate the token. This is the expected action.

[Destroying the session](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1340) will log the user out of the app but not invalidate the token. Seeing that you are saving it to a database, you are probably requesting access longer than two hours which is past the limitation of a short lived token.

Also as you are using a page  you can use scenario 5 at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

> When a user grants an app the manage_pages permission, the app is able
>   to obtain page access tokens for pages that the user administers by
>   querying the [User ID]/accounts Graph API endpoint. With the migration
>   enabled, when using a short-lived user access token to query this
>   endpoint, the page access tokens obtained are short-lived as well.
>
> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access
>   token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a
>   long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint
>   will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that
>   a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring
>   user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access
>   permission.

Comment: Forgive me for being naive, but where exactly do I insert `$facebook->destroySession()` if I'm only using the Auth URL and Code Function above? :/

Comment: @JodyHeavener Wherever you want to logout. How exactly are you logging out?